# unable to clear logs stored by RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I have RabbitMQ running on my test server. The log file has grown into 20 GB and i would like to clear it. I even have a scheduler to delete it timely but it is not working due to below issue.

Issue:
If i delete the log file either manually or via a scheudled script, the file automatically gets restored. How do i get this fixed?

Rabbitmq.Config file looks like below,

```
[ 
{rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [1111]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"D:\\RabbitMQ Server\\Certs\\certname.cer"},
                    {certfile,"D:\\RabbitMQ Server\\Certs\\cer_cername_host.cer"},
                    {keyfile,"D:\\RabbitMQ Server\\Certs\\cer_cername_host.pfx"},
                    {verify,verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
   ]}
   ].
```

Comment: i would still appreciate if any one can explain the config file for me relating to logs

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue.

Acually it was an issue of config file not having correct name. Someone stored the config file name as rabbitmq copy.config rather than rabbitmq.config.

I can see underm overview sections it is refering to the correct Rabbitmq CONFIG. previously it was not picking up a config.

[image]